# Making coordinates out of arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, coordinates

So, I have two arrays:

```
X'

ans =

    2.5770    2.5974    2.1031    2.7813    2.6083    2.9498    3.0053    3.3860

>> Y'

ans =

    0.7132    0.5908    1.9988    1.0332    1.3301    1.1064    1.3522    1.3024
```

I would like to combine n-th members of two arrays together, and than plot those coordinates on graph.
So it should be:

```
{(2.5770,0.7132), (2.5974,0.5908)...}
```

Is this possible to do? If so, how?

Comment: Why don't you just do `plot(X,Y,'+')`?

Comment: Im not so good with MATLAB, so I wasn't familiar with this. It looks great, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Schorsch showed that it is simple to plot, but just to answer the question as asked in the title, you can combine the arrays into coordinates by just arranging the vectors like rectangles.

Your `x` and `y` are vertical, so you can put them side-by-side in a 2-column matrix:
`combined = [x  y]`

or transform and have 2 rows: `combined = [x' ; y']`

(Because they're vertical, what you don't want is these, which would concatenate them out into one long column or row: `[x ; y]` or `[x' y']`)

Just to be clear, though, this is not needed for plotting.

**Edit:** A suggested edit asked what happens if you `plot(combined)`.  That depends if it's the horizontal or vertical version.  In any case, plotting a 2x? matrix won't plot x vs. y.  It plots all of the columns versus the simple indices 1,2,3,...   So the first way I defined `combined` will make two lines, plotting x and y on the y-axis against their indices on the x-axis, and the second version of `combined` will make a strange plot with the all of the values of x plotted in a vertical column where x=1 and all of the points of y beside those at x=2.